# How can you get a python dictionary to have duplicate keys holding values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on an assignment. Is there anyway a dictionary can have duplicate keys and hold the same or different values. Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
dict = {
        'Key1' : 'Helo', 'World'
        'Key1' : 'Helo'
        'Key1' : 'Helo', 'World'
       }
```

I tried doing this but when I associate any value to key1, it gets added to the same key1.
Is this possible with a dictionary? If not what other data structure I can use to implement this process?

Comment: So what will `dict['Key1']` pull up?

Answer (score 3):

## Use dictionaries of lists to hold multiple values.

One way to have multiple values to a key is to use a dictionary of lists.

```
x = { 'Key1' : ['Hello', 'World'],
      'Key2' : ['Howdy', 'Neighbor'],
      'Key3' : ['Hey',   'Dude']
    }
```

To get the list you want (or make a new one), I recommend using setdefault.

```
my_list = x.setdefault(key, [])
```

Example:

```
>>> x = {}
>>> x['abc'] = [1,2,3,4]
>>> x
{'abc': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
>>> x.setdefault('xyz', [])
[]
>>> x.setdefault('abc', [])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x
{'xyz': [], 'abc': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

## Using `defaultdict` for the same functionality

To make this even easier, the [collections module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) has a `defaultdict` object that simplifies this. Just pass it a constructor/factory.

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(list)
x['key1'].append(12)
x['key1'].append(13)
```

You can also use dictionaries of dictionaries or even dictionaries of sets.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd = defaultdict(dict)
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {})
>>> dd['x']['a'] = 23
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'x': {'a': 23}})
>>> dd['x']['b'] = 46
>>> dd['y']['a'] = 12
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'y': {'a': 12}, 'x': {'a': 23, 'b': 46}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
list_of_values = [['Hello', 'World'], 'Hello', ['Hello', 'World']]
for v in list_of_values:
    d['Key1'].append(v)

print d
```

This will deal with duplicate keys, and instead of overwriting the key, it will append something to that list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are unique to the data.  Consider using some other value for a key or consider using a different data structure to hold this data.

for example:

- don't use a persons address as a unique key because several people might live there.
- a person's social security number or a drivers license is a much better unique id of a person.
- you can create your own id to force it to be unique.